# Command not found: nexus

Tags: prisma, nexus-prisma

I'm using nexus and nexus-prisma-plugin for my backend. I pulled my backend from GitHub and installed all packages. Now when I want to run the nexus server I got the error zsh: command not found: nexus.

I also work on a Linux computer and there it's working without any problems. Now on my Mac it don't work. But why? Do I have to add nexus to path? But how?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you running the server? Is `nexus` in your `package.json` and installed locally? Also check this repo that I have created as well so that you get a better idea: https://github.com/ryands17/nexus-framework-auth

Comment: Nexus is installed in my package.json. How can I check if it is installed locally? Now I added npm start script to package.json which runs nexus dev. This works for me but is not a clear solution.

Comment: Thanks for your example. I also had some issues with Shield which I solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet for **Mac** :

1. "*./nexus start*"

**once you have run the above command in the terminal, you will receive the below message**

*Starting nexus*

2. Then launch the http://localhost:8081/ >> To play around the nexus.

**other commands**:

./nexus {start|stop|run|run-redirect|status|restart|force-reload}